# How to send a cfn signal with curl (without AWS CLI, AWS SDK)?

Tags: amazon-web-services, curl, amazon-ec2

I have an ec2 instance **without** aws cli installed, not connected to the internet.

I want to send a `cfn signal` in `user data` manually - with `curl` to the `AutoScalingGroup` that created this instance.

I set up a VPC end point and tried to send this request (based on the request that is sent with `cfn-signal` application which ran on a different ec2 machine)

```
unique_id=`curl -s http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id`
signature=`curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/dynamic/instance-identity/signature | tr -d '\n'`
document=`curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/dynamic/instance-identity/document | base64`
authorization="u'CFN_V1 $document:$signature"
response="{ \"Status\" : \"SUCCESS\", \"ContentType\" : \"JSON\", \"StackName\" : \"MY_STACK_NAME\", \"Version\": \"2010-05-15\", \"UniqueId\" : \"$unique_id\", \"Action\": \"SignalResource\", \"LogicalResourceId\": \"AutoScalingGroup\" }"

curl -H "Authorization: $authorization" -H "Accept: application/json" -H "User-Agent: CloudFormation Tools" --data-binary "$response" 'https://cloudformation.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/'
```

I get a possible error `curl: (52) Empty reply from server` and timeout occurs so the signal doesn't arrive. timeout occurs eventually.

Is there a documentation of the protocol for this type of API request? [cfn-signal](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/cfn-signal.html) only depicts usage with AWS CLI, or - is there something wrong with the code?

Comment: If you don't have connectivity to the Internet you'll need a VPC Endpoint to reach `cloudformation.us-east-1.amazonaws.com`.

Comment: The target for the `curl` response is on the Internet. You need some form of Internet connectivity to send the signal (eg NAT Gateway). @kdgregory is suggesting that a VPC Endpoint for CloudFormation might be sufficient to send to the target, so that is worth trying first.

Comment: @kdgregory I have a VPC endpoint defined, and if I send a `ping` to that address I get a local ip address.

Comment: Timeout indicates a problem with network reachability, often an incorrectly configured security group. Can't give you any more recommendations with the information that you've provided.